# How to sync user password between 3 different services when they are hashed in different point of time?

Tags: database, microservices

I have 3 microservices that hold particular user information including their sign-in credentials (email + password). If the services are `A`, `B`, and `C` then the user "John" will have his info stored separately in all three of these services' database.

Now, the user info in service `A` is updated at an earlier point of time, and at that moment it is not predictable whether services `B` or `C` will definitely be activated to be used by that particular user. So, there is no point in creating an entry in `B` and `C` for "John". But, as "John" activates `B` or `C` at a later point of time, the system can only have access to the hashed password.

It is to be noted that the service `C` requires the password to be stored in encrypted form so that it can be decrypted later. So, merely storing the hashed value in all 3 services is not feasible, neither do we want all 3 of them to have encrypted password.

What is a feasible solution to sync the password between the services by maintaining the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach implies a lot of problems in addition to the one you already described yourself. I recommend to look into Federated Identity (using OAuth2 and OpenID Connect) which fits for Microservices architectures.

Basically, this means that authentication and credentials handling is performed by a separate highly available and scalable service (usually referred to as identity provider or authorization server) that only does that - handling user credentials, identity and access control - and does it well.

It handles login and issues access tokens which are then sent to your Microservices along with the requests. As each Microservice will trust this identity provider it will be able to verify that the token is valid and was issued by this identity provider (this happens by validating the token with a public key). And the token contains information like user id and information about what actions are allowed with this token.

The identity provider can be a cloud service like Okta, Auth0, Azure AD B2C, etc. (see https://openid.net/developers/certified/#OPServices) or host an identity provider on your own, if you are not able to access cloud services, by using ready-to-use libraries available for your technology stack (https://openid.net/developers/certified/#OPLibs).

So there is no need to store user credentials in each Microservice and sync this information between them. I would consider such an approach as an anti-pattern.

The federated authentication approach also allows to solve other problems such as single-sign-on.

If you are new to that topic it can be a little overwhelming at first but it's something you can't get around if you really want to have all the advantages a Microservices architecture can provide.

This article might help you get started:
https://nordicapis.com/how-to-control-user-identity-within-microservices/